# Is it ethical for advisors to automatically coauthor papers?

Tags: authorship

I work in a field (Philosophy) where co-authorship is uncommon and advisors and grad students very seldomly co-author a paper. I've seen a lot of posts on Academia.se though about the ethics of co-authoring papers with mentors, such [as this question.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19319/is-it-better-to-submit-a-paper-to-an-important-journal-without-the-supervisor-na)

My sense is that it must be somewhat common in the natural sciences for the head of the lab/dissertation advisor to be automatically added as a co-author to every paper that his or her graduate students produce.

My questions are:

- Is this really common, and if so, in which fields?
- Is this really ethical?

My view is that adding your name to something that you had no part in creating is just plagiarism: it's taking credit for the work of others.

The opposite argument, that the work wouldn't have been possible without the PI's grant funding also cuts no ice. I wouldn't have been able to write my dissertation if my parents hadn't had sex, but that doesn't mean they should get credit as coauthoring my work.

That's the way it seems to me, but maybe somebody from these fields can give us a better rationale for (what seems to be) the widespread practice.

**Edit:**
Another argument against the practice. Suppose I'm a billionaire who knows nothing about science, but I take it into my head that I want to be (regarded as) a famous scientist. Suppose I just spend billions of dollars to fund other people to do research. But, I ask each of those people to come and report to me for fifteen minutes ever week about what they've worked on, or discovered that week. Then, every time one of them finds a result, I demand that my name be added to the paper as a co-author, since we have "discussed" the work in progress and it is, after all, by my grace that the funds for the work have been provided. Suppose I just have hundreds of these postdocs, producing thousands of papers a year, all of which I am a coauthor for.

Now ask yourself if I really deserve to be regarded as a famous scientist at all? It seems to me that I don't, because I haven't done any of the science--I haven't suggested any research methods, I haven't designed any experiments, I haven't collected any data, I haven't even helped junior researchers know the shape of the existing literature. You might regard my existence as good for science in some sense--you might think of me as a beneficial patron of the sciences. But you wouldn't think of me as a scientist, right? And you wouldn't think I deserved to be considered for a Nobel Prize, or membership in the American Academy of the Arts and Sciences, or whatever. If I demanded that I be given those awards because of the thousands and thousands of papers that I have coauthored, which have been cited tens of thousands of times, you would call me an idiot, right? We give those prizes for discovery, not for being rich. The same thing is true of tenure too. You shouldn't be able to buy your role as a tenured professor. You should have to prove that you, personally, are capable of making a serious contribution to your field. And of course you demonstrate that capability by publishing papers.

So when a prof is automatically added as a coauthor to a paper that he or she did not contribute to in any way except financially, then she is trying to *buy* a reputation as a scholar, or the other perks like tenure or membership in the AAAS that come with that reputation in just the same kind of way that the absurd billionaire is doing.

Comment: Interestingly, I had a first-author paper with a co-author adviser who demanded I take his name off the paper before putting it on arXiv. He didn't tell me exactly why, but perhaps his rationale was that he didn't think it was ethical to "leech" onto a student's paper.

Comment: @Suresh: The questions overlap but in my opinion are not identical.  Moreover both questions are (still in my opinion, of course) just about the most important questions one could ask on a site like this.  So I think they should be encouraged and people should think hard about giving good, broadly applicable answers.

Comment: Your example of a billionaire who knows nothing about science doesn't hold water. The billionaire clearly made no intellectual contribution, since s/he knows nothing about science. Discussing something with the head of a scientific laboratory for 15 minutes a week could result in a significant scientific contribution, though this is not guaranteed.  (For example, "I can't get X to work." "Did you try adjustment Y?" Next week, "Hey, Y allowed me to get great results!")

Comment: Here's a conversation I have with my grad student colleagues occasionally. "Hey, look at this for me. I've got these three premises that should entail this conclusion, but I can't get the proof." "Yeah, you missed a negation here." "oh, yeah. there it is." I would never want to be a coauthor for something like that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby They don't even need to suggest anything, [just make the them talk/think aloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: @izkata, are you suggesting making the rubber duck a co-author?

Comment: The billionare in your example would not in fact become known as a scientist in this situation, nor would he merit (or be awarded) any of the skill certifications you mention. But with giving authorship credit, the scientists are getting off easy, actually - I'd expect him to require something closer to having his personal logo be included in the header or footer of every single page.

Comment: I think they key word in your question is "automatically". Most of the time a research advisor ought to be able to help you make your paper better to the point of deserving co-authorship. And in many fields, the name of a well known co-author will increase the chances of the paper being read and cited - which will benefit the first author. In some sense, the "authority"'s name on the paper conveys additional credibility that goes beyond the fact that the work passed peer review. Unless the journal is known for exceptionally tight review standards, that helps.

Comment: Nobody has a problem with people who deserve credit getting credit. What I have a problem with is people who don't deserve credit getting it. Leave the issue of how the practice victimizes grad students aside. It would still be wrong for a prof to receive credit for work she didn't do.

Comment: With the benefit of having been through grad school and am now doing something else, I would say yes its ethical, because of the funding situation.  Natural sciences grad studentships are based on grant funding.  The advisor had to create the grant in the first place.  The work the student is doing is based on the grant.  So yes the advisor really should get a large share of the credit even if they did nothing to directly support the paper.

Comment: I agree with @shane that it is totally unethical to add your name in manuscript just because of administrative reasons no matter whether your are advisor or head of laboratory or any other person influencing the author just because of administrative reasons.

Comment: With your billionaire scientist idea: actually, I would have no problem with putting someone who funded billions of dollars of science projects, and actually talked 15 minutes a week with the scientist, as a coauthor.

Comment: @CliffAB The standard way to correctly attribute the provider of funding is in a daggered/asterisked footnote on the first page of the paper.

Comment: Some of the answers on this question might give you insights about the field differences: [When should a supervisor be an author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/644/66)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**No, automatic co-authorship is not ethical – irrespectively of the discipline!**

The following is from the ["DFG Proposals for Safeguarding Good Scientific Practice"](https://www.dfg.de/download/pdf/foerderung/rechtliche_rahmenbedingungen/gute_wissenschaftliche_praxis/kodex_gwp_en.pdf) (pp.82f, emphasis added), which, for instance, strictly forbids "automatic" co-authorships and gives a couple of common negative examples:

> Authors of an original scientific publication shall be all those, and only those, who have made **significant contributions** to the conception of studies or experiments, to the generation, analysis and interpretation of the data, and to preparing the manuscript, and who have consented to its publication, thereby assuming responsibility for it. [...]
> Therefore, the following contributions on their own **are not sufficient to justify authorship**:

> - merely **organisational responsibility for** obtaining the funds for the research,

- providing standard investigation material,
- the training of staff in standard methods,
- merely technical work on data collection,
- merely technical support, such as only providing equipment or experimental animals,
- regularly providing datasets only,
- **only reading the manuscript** without substantial contributions to its content,
- **directing an institution** or working unit in which the publication originates

> Help of this kind can be acknowledged in footnotes or in the foreword.

In fact, DFG (the German Research Council) requires you to sign strict adherence to this ethical code on each and every grant proposal. Other funding agencies have similar regulations.

Comment: +1: this seems like a very important answer.  Some people on this site have suggested that in certain scientific fields the practice is just not regarded as unethical.  One wonders why such a basic academic principle -- which for instance makes contact with the universal condemnation of plagiarism -- could be so field-dependent.  This answer provides convincing evidence that **there are some common ethical principles** at work here.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I think the issue is that there are also **unethical traditions in some fields** that are so common that young researchers just internalize them without ever questioning them. One trigger for DFG to make this explicit was the extreme case of a med school professor, who had "co-authored" more than 400 papers in a single year. Still, surprisingly many researchers I have talked too consider this as "pretty normal".

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that writing successful grant proposals, that take a long time, are not considered a metric in the academic career; so there is a tendency to unethical practices.

Comment: @Davidmh, why think that winning grants isn't a metric in an academic career. Everyone I've ever known who won a grant put the name, date, and amount of the grant on his or her CV. That's an appropriate way to take credit, and I think everyone in academia appreciates those kinds of contributions--especially deans who make crucial hiring/promotion decisions.

Comment: @shane Some people put the positions of their former PhD students (makes sense if many of them go to Caltech and Princeton), but in many cases, only articles are counted (or mostly counted). After all, "he has 20 papers in Nature" sounds way better than "he funded 20 papers in Nature".

Comment: But those same people also claim the PhD students they've directed elsewhere on the CV right? under a section titled "Dissertations Directed" or something like that? If so, then they've taken the appropriate credit for the work they've done, and their peers will take that into account when evaluating them for promotion, merit pay, etc. But it would be unreasonable to count the students that way AND then also demand to be the automatic coauthor of all of their papers.

Comment: "have consented to its publication, thereby assuming responsibility for it" This is an important test. If the paper is later found to be flawed, no author should be able to disclaim responsibility. i.e. every author should be involved enough to know if the paper is fishy.

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that those guidelines do not rule out automatic authorship for individuals providing _intellectual_ responsibility for obtaining the funds for research, and do forbid the standard practice in experimental particle physics, gravitational wave physics, and other 100+ author science. Though I appreciate the good intuition behind them, I also appreciate that they're principally convenient guidelines for a funding body which wants a simple interpretation of ‘authorship’ which supports a nice measurable connection between author statistics and funding decisions.

Answer (score 38):

> Is this really common, and if so, in which fields?

I guess it is reasonably common in many fields. As a rule of thumb, it seems to me that the more applied a field is, the more likely you are to see groups where the lab head co-authors every or almost every paper in the lab. In my field (software engineering), I would say at least 50% - 75% of all groups operate like this. Academia.SE tells me that this is not the case e.g., in Theoretical CS.

Note that this does not *necessarily* mean that the lab head is added to each paper without contribution (although there are certainly groups where it means exactly that). In some cases, it is just that all research in a lab directly runs through the lab head (i.e., nobody works on research without the direct involvement of the lab head). In such cases, co-authorship on all papers may be academically warranted (but this might actually be the worse practice in reality, as it allows for no growth to independence at all for the PhD students and postdocs in the lab).

> Is this really ethical?

I would argue that things are more complicated than you seem to think, mostly because the funding argument that you claim "holds no ice" is in fact not so bad. Your comparison with your parents having sex is pretty silly. Big research labs depend on senior researchers acquiring grant money. This takes **a lot** of time - time, that said researchers cannot use to write actual papers. Researchers on any level are mostly evaluated via papers. Under these circumstances, if senior researchers don't get a "kickback" on some level from the money they acquire, what would motivate them to write grant proposals in the first place?

There is also the added difficulty that in many STEM fields it is just darn difficult to decide whether somebody has *made a contribution* (see also here: [What are the minimum contributions required for co-authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/what-are-the-minimum-contributions-required-for-co-authorship?lq=1)). Is discussing ideas enough? What if all the important ideas and suggestions came from the advisor? Oftentimes, the research work of a PhD student is basically an implementation of a high-level plan laid out by the advisor in the funding proposal. In that case, has the advisor not by default "contributed" to all papers?

Comment: "nobody works on research without the direct involvement of the lab head". What does this mean, exactly? The head cannot be participating in all the projects in a large lab, or even in a medium-sized one.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I guess this depends on your definition of 'participating' (and also on large/medium-sized). A lab head can certainly forbid (or strongly discourage) research that does not directly go back to his own ideas, as written down in grant proposals and position papers.

Comment: "can certainly forbid (or strongly discourage) research". Well, that's an extremely loose definition of participation. Giving orders does not equal participation in my book.

Comment: @FaheemMitha It is not so much that he contributes by giving orders, it is more that no research work to which he has not contributed can be done. I have seen this in a few labs with very tight research plans. I don't think this is exactly a model system, but it certainly happens.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. That's sounds like an "interesting" setup. Regardless, I don't see how a single individual can scale so far as to be significantly contributing to on a bunch of different projects at the same time.

Comment: @FaheemMitha It's the old "you have been hired to work on this grant, you shouldn't have time to work on something else as well" argument. You can see in popping up on Academia.SE sometimes as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13906/discussion-between-xleitix-and-faheem-mitha)

Comment: "Your comparison with your parents having sex is pretty silly. Big research labs depend on senior researchers acquiring grant money. This takes a lot of time - time, that said researchers cannot use to write actual papers." That argument would hold just as true of the dean and the president of the university as it does of the head of the lab. Why should the the head of the lab get credit, just because he paid for the materials, or researchers that made a project possible? There are other ways to give credit for securing grants, and funding research. But attribution as a coauthor isn't one.

Comment: I think the idea of X implementing Y's plan should count as a reasonable co-authorship situation--X and Y both contributed. But "discussion" isn't contributing. If X just tells Y what X is working on, without Y suggesting any methods, or background knowledge or whatever else, then X and Y are clearly "discussing" but also obviously Y isn't contributing anything to X's work and so shouldn't be a coauthor.

Comment: @Shane I am not sure how one would realistically "discuss" without providing any input of value at all.

Comment: @xLeitix, to see the phenomenon in action, I recommend attending a panel discussion at the American Philosophical Association.

Comment: It's fair that The Money gets acknowledged, but is authorship the right place?

Comment: @Raphael, nobody has a problem with those who provide funding getting acknowledged in the acknowledgements section of a paper. But authorship is a totally different thing.

Comment: @shane: That's what I was (trying to) say(ing).

Answer (score 31):

In fundamental mathematics, at least in France, the custom is for advisors never to co-author (important) papers with their students. If an advisor does coauthor a paper with a PhD student, then it is assumed that he or she had to help the student more than should be expected, and this can prevent the student from getting a job afterward.

This goes to the point of being arguably unethical in the opposite way than asked in the question, as most of the time advisors do have a role (if only of suggesting the question and the angle of attack) in PhD student papers.

Comment: Well, in case there *was* significant input by the advisor, this is unethical as well.

Comment: The point is that this unethical aspect, while certainly arguable, is on the community itself. A given advisor that would not follow the custom would put a strong handicap on its PhD students.

Comment: The term "unethical" is bullshit. Is it morally wrong to not give coauthorship to the mentor? Of course not, because the math community does not expect it.

Answer (score 16):

The correct analogy to draw in fields where grant-writing is a critical aspect of the research is architecture: the act of preparing the grant is akin to doing the conceptual design of a new building; the work of the graduate students and postdocs (or other researchers) is the research equivalent of fleshing out the design into a practical design, and converting it into a real building. The master architect (the one overseeing the vision) is going to get a substantial amount of credit, regardless of not being the one to plan everything out to the finest detail. But the important thing is that the end product (the building in one case, the research in the other) would not result without the initial rough sketches for the specific project (the conceptual design or the grant proposal).

This is very different from the billionaire example provided above, because writing a grant requires the construction of a specific framework in which the research will be carried out, not just handing over money to others to do work within some grandiose but completely unspecific vision.

Now, as a further practical matter, very few advisors are "absentee landlords" who merely acquire the grant, and then do nothing else. They almost certainly don't run the code or perform the experiments, but they are active in helping to interpreting the data, design future experiments, and evaluating and editing the manuscripts that are produced. In part, this is a matter of safeguarding one's reputation: if you let people publish bad work under your name, your reputation will suffer as a result in the long run.

Comment: _But the important thing is that the end product would not result without the initial rough sketches._ — No, that's not enough.  _All_ research builds on earlier work.  The same argument implies that every paper on cosmology should have Albert Einstein as a coauthor.

Comment: _very few advisors are "absentee landlords"_ — [citation needed]

Comment: @JeffE: No, it doesn't, unless Einstein wrote the grant and specified the major design elements of the project. (I hope my edit has clarified this.)

Comment: I agree that a student who is carrying out part of a project that someone else has received a grant to work on should list the PI as a coauthor if she is using the resources of the grant.  But the OP asked about more than this: "My sense is that it must be somewhat common in the natural sciences for the head of the lab/dissertation advisor to be automatically added as a co-author to every paper that his or her graduate students produce." In other words, the question is about advisors being added as authors to papers for work done which *has not been* commissioned as part of the grant research.

Comment: That presupposes a fact not in evidence: that students are going to produce papers outside of the main grant research. Once again, in fields where advisor-provided financing is the norm, such behavior is very much the exception, not the rule. (If I'm providing their full salary, I expect them to be working on the project full-time unless they've cleared it with me in advance.)

Comment: Suppose you get a grant to work on a problem in field X. You want to know whether or not p, and you get a grant to investigate the problem. Then, in the course of that work, one of your students discovers that q, which follows from the fact that p, but q isn't really important in field X, but it is important in Y. Then the student writes up the proof that if p, then q and publishes it in the Journal of Y Studies. You didn't know that p implied q when you wrote the grant, and you didn't discover that fact either. I'll grant you credit for p, but you don't deserve any for q, or the connection.

Comment: If all the advisor does is provide funding? Perhaps. But if the advisor is actively involved in the work—again, in planning experiments, troubleshooting, interpreting data, and reviewing and editing the manuscript—then the advisor still deserves credit. Also of note: this is again a very rare case in such fields. Not non-existent, as I do know of a few such cases, but we're talking less than one in a thousand (at least in my field).

Comment: At the same time, though, if the student's funding is dependent on X, then he better not spend vast amounts of time working on field Y without letting his advisor know in advance what's going on. (This is doubly true depending on the source of the funding—especially if it's coming from either a three-letter agency or a corporate sponsor.)

Comment: aeismail: I am not "presupposing facts not in evidence": I am considering a certain case.  The question asked whether an advisor's name should *automatically* go on all papers the student produces.  In other words, the OP is inquiring whether a universally quantified statement is valid.  To argue against such a statement it suffices to exhibit a counterexample.  That is what I am claiming to do.

Comment: "If I'm providing their full salary, I expect them to be working on the project full-time unless they've cleared it with me in advance." This attitude would in my field be frowned upon.  What does "full-time" mean for a graduate student?  Many students spend much more than 40 hours a week on their teaching and research.  If you are funding a student then you have the right to specify a certain amount of time in which they work directly for you.  Whatever they choose to do outside of that time is certainly their own choice, and in my experience the best students will do other work in this time.

Comment: Full-time means 40 hours per week (or whatever full-time is in your location). But the critical issue is foreknowledge: I don't have a problem with students going off-topic—but I would want to know about it at the time. Another reason this is important is that in experimental fields such side-projects often involve use of limited resources (materials, equipment use, supercomputer time, etc.). The researcher needs to be able to show that the diversion of resources and their labor isn't going to have an adverse effect on the existing project.

Comment: aeismail: In the US, graduate school is not a nine to five job: no one is checking to make sure that students clock in and clock out at certain times, and most graduate students do a large amount of work after hours and on weekends.  Moreover students are not employees of faculty (and no faculty that I know of are really "paying" students; money coming from grants is ultimately coming from another source).  The idea that students need to clear everything they do with a faculty member would be considered a disrespectful treatment of students by many faculty I know.

Comment: I certainly agree that students who use materials or equipment need to clear that usage with the personnel in charge.  In many branches of academia, no materials or equipment beyond libraries and the internet are needed to do research.  I know of no branch of academia in which sitting, thinking and writing is not a major component of research.  Students are free to sit, think and write without faculty permission, and it distresses me that any students anywhere would be discouraged from doing so.

Comment: I don't make my students fill out timecards, but ultimately, I have to certify that my budget has been appropriately spent. If my grant is for X, and my student has spent so much time working on Theta, that nothing happened in X, that can be a problem for both of us. If the student is making satisfactory progress on topic X, then spending some time exploring other areas isn't a problem. But if it's going to amount to a substantial fraction of their effort for an extended period of time, that's something I need to know so I can plan for it (and help justify it, if possible).

Comment: "If the student is making satisfactory progress on topic X, then spending some time exploring other areas isn't a problem. But if it's going to amount to a substantial fraction of their effort for an extended period of time, that's something I need to know so I can plan for it (and help justify it, if possible)."  That sounds entirely reasonable to me.

Answer (score 11):

This depends on many factors, and there is no general answer. In a field like experimental particle physics, you can have a paper with 500 authors. These experiments are huge collaborations. For people doing theoretical work in the sciences, it's more common to have only one or two authors; the question is then whether the adviser made a significant contribution.

Yes, it does happen sometimes that people get added as coauthors when they shouldn't. At a lab where I once worked, the director of the lab got his name on every paper done by anybody at the lab, even if he had made no contribution. (His c.v. proudly listed his vast number of scientific publications.) I once had a coauthor who refused to read and comment on the paper before it was submitted, but who also wanted his name on it. He was backed by our PI, because he had done work on the experiment.

In the natural sciences, the norm is basically that if you made a significant contribution to the work, your name goes on the paper. Typically a grad student's adviser *will* make a significant contribution to any work the student carries out.

Comment: I don't have a problem with people who made a contribution being added. What I have a problem with is getting credit for somebody else's work.

Answer (score 9):

I doubt I have anything too original to say here, but I couldn't resist a chance to add my 2c. This might be the most fraught question in academia, as least if you are a student or a post-doc.

> Is it ethical for advisors to automatically coauthor papers?

I assume that by advisor you are also including a postdocs PI, for example. So let us consider the question as this more general one. The basic answer in my opinion, is... No, of course, not.

I've seen various positions/justifications on/for this. They include:

1. That's just the way it is. The advisor provides the funding. Without
   him, you would have no funding, no job, and no paper. So be
   grateful. This might be described as the "capitalist justification"
   for this practice. Similar viewpoints are expressed to justify why
   capitalism and capitalists are good things.
2. Well, the advisor is providing value even if you don't think or know
   it. It is easy for a junior researcher to underestimate the value of
   an overarching research plan, and the value in discussion and the
   perspective of a senior researcher.
3. Well, the senior faculty need a payoff, or else why is it worth
   their while? This was expressed by @xLeitix for example.

That might be some value/validity in all these viewpoints, but I personally don't think that any of these is a justification for such practices.

As far as 1 goes, you can basically use the same justification for a sweatshop.

As far as 2, I think that the help provided by one individual spreading himself as thin as the kinds of people we are talking about do, is likely to be realistically very low, unless the person in question is very energetic and very talented. Such people are rare. Plus senior people don't usually have that kind of energy anyway. Also, research questions are just too hard, complicated, and non-obvious. You need to dig in. But you can't dig in 20 holes at the same time.
Additionally, in the kind of complex multi-disciplinary areas that are getting more common these days, it is increasingly difficult to have a sufficiently broad skill-set to be able to keep up with more than a fraction of what is going on in a typical research lab.

My experience of mentors/advisors contributions is that their contributions tended to be useless/rubbish because they did not really understand the issues, either because they didn't have or didn't want to take the time, or their training had simply not equipped them to do so.

3 is really the hardest to respond to; I'm not sure I have a good response. However, it is not really a justification so much as a pragmatic observation.

So, to the subquestions

> Is this really common, and if so, in which fields?

It is really hard to know this. You can't pass out a survey which includes a box to tick saying "yes, I'm a crook and fraud". However... @xLeitix writes

> I guess it is reasonably common in many fields. As a rule of thumb, it
>   seems to me that the more applied a field is, the more likely you are
>   to see groups where the lab head co-authors every or almost every
>   paper in the lab. In my field (software engineering), I would say at
>   least 50% - 75% of all groups operate like this.

Based on my experience, I think this sounds pretty accurate, though I would not venture any percentages. I've worked in more theoretical fields, notably Math and Statistics, and in Biomed type fields; this kind of thing is much less common in the theoretical fields, and practically the norm in Biomed. In fact, I didn't see *any* of this in Math. I don't think this is because mathematicians are inherently any more virtuous than anyone else. I think it is because 
applied work just inherently has more overhead in practical terms than theoretical work, at least in the implementation end of the work. If a mathematician has an idea, he has to prove it, which may not be so easy, but once he has done that, he is basically done. In an applied area, if you have an idea, you are just getting started. You have to collect data and/or perform experiments, probably write some code, write the paper, make figures, etc. etc. So there is just more room for monkey work which a junior person can do.

If I am an applied researcher, I'm probably under immense pressure to perform, to get tenure, or maybe just keep my job. I could try to be good, and contribute to every paper that I am putting my name on, but given the immense overhead of applied work as described above, and also, given that your colleagues are probably happily abusing the system, there is immense temptation, I imagine, to abuse the system as well. Just to keep up.

In any case, in my experience, most people who do this seems to have completely internalized this behavior, and seem to take it for granted.

> Is this really ethical?

No, of course not. Ultimately, my objections are really that of straight morality. I think it is just *wrong*. These practices are a form of fraud and a form of reputation/credit theft. Granted, in the grand scheme of things they are fairly minor offenses, but regardless...

I think Shane (the poster) makes a good point with his billionaire hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks Faheem. I think the way to respond to your #3 is just to say that there are other ways of giving PIs credit for mentoring grads. At every US university I've ever heard of, tenure decisions are made in terms of: (i) scholarship, (ii) teaching, and (iii) department service. Getting grant funding and mentoring PhDs should count under (iii). Trying to count those papers as research, i.e. get them to fall under (i) as well, strikes me as pernicious double counting.

Comment: Good points, @shane.

Comment: I like a lot of this answer. What concerns me, though, is that you seem to think very badly of senior researchers in general ("senior people don't usually have that kind of energy anyway", "research questions are just too hard, complicated, and non-obvious", "their contributions tended to be useless/rubbish", etc.). For individuals this may be true, but in general - how do you think those senior researchers *became* senior researchers? By not having the slightest clue how to do research? That seems unlikely. Occam's razor suggests that their might have (also) been a problem on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @xLeitix: First, I'm not talking about all "senior researchers", just those that have "advised" me in the Biomed area. So, we're talking about a small group of individuals. I would like to think my experiences are untypical, but my experience talking to other people has suggested, that, sadly, it is not. Of course, without direct experience, I have no way of knowing. One point that is worth noting, if one has a bad experience with individual 1, then this significantly increases the odds of having more bad experiences later. Why?

Comment: Because your first bad experience could have caused a career hit, which can be difficult to recover from and would have limited your choices. To put it in statistical parlance, bad experiences are not independent. As to "but in general - how do you think those senior researchers became senior researchers? By not having the slightest clue how to do research?" I never said they didn't have the slightest clue how to do research, or even implied it. Read my post again.

Comment: _Getting grant funding and mentoring PhDs should count under (iii)_ — At least at my university, grant funding is used as evidence of scholarly reputation (i), and mentoring students falls under education (ii).  Yes, both are taken very seriously.

Comment: @JeffE, why would getting a grant testify to a person's chops *as a scholar*? I get that grant writing is important, and that it is a difficult skill to acquire, and that a person who wins lots of grants deserves recognition of that fact. But what winning grants tells me is that a person knows how to write a good grant app, not that they are a really capable researcher. EDIT: It also seems likely to me that people who are good researchers would also tend to be good grant writers too--so the two skillsets might in practice be found together often. But still they are conceptually distinct.

Comment: At least at NSF, research proposals are evaluated by a panel of peers, who tend to favor proposals _written by researchers with proven track records_.  A great-sounding proposal won't get funded if the panel doesn't believe the proposer can actually carry out the proposed research.  Conversely, panels are much more willing to believe in the _future_ quality and impact of someone's research if their _past_ research has demonstrably high quality and impact.  It's a textbook example of the [Matthew effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_effect).

Comment: That said, grants are definitely not taken as the _primary_ indicator of high-quality scholarship.

Comment: @Jigg The analogy is of the person with the money sitting in his/her office with a piece of paper saying { they are the PI / the owner of the actory }, telling everyone else what to do, and profiting from their labor. Here money == grants. IMO the analogy is pretty good.

Answer (score 7):

I work in pure mathematics, where advisors are not co-authors unless they have significant input. My perception is that the convention the question speaks of occurs primarily in the laboratory sciences, so my point of view is that of an outsider

Nevertheless, I do not consider the practice unethical. First of all, there is no deception, because in those fields it is well-established convention that the last name on the paper is the lab PI, and other scientists reading the paper will recognize that she didn't contribute to the paper in the same way the first author did, but that the research was performed in her lab with her grant money.

Secondly, the lab PI doesn't just bring in the money, she also decides which direction the lab's research should focus on, and she often has to organize a large team of people- something that an advisor never has to do in say, mathematics. This is where the billionaire analogy breaks down. If your hypothetical benefactor also has to make decisions what equipment to buy, which skills to recruit in postdocs and grad students, and which (and how much) resources are worth pouring into which scientific questions, then yes, she deserves last author credit.

Thirdly (and I may be a little unfair in this point) my perception is that the standards of co-authorship are lower in the lab sciences compared to math and philosophy, e.g. people who perform tedious monkeying with equipment, or perform statistical analyses in data get their names on papers  despite not contributing to the "thinking part" of the project. So if Joe who did nothing but mess with a spectrometer for a couple of days has his name as third author, then Susie who manages the lab should get her name on it too.

Answer (score 7):

Answers to your question of the ethics of co-authorship need to consider what is the role of (or signal conveyed by) authorship in a publication. This role may 1) differ among disciplines  and 2) be evolving all the time.

In the case of large research groups or collaborative projects—as some seen in genetics or physics—the roles of a head researcher involve managing the direction of the research and to create an environment where that research can thrive. The latter may involve obtaining funding, hiring post-docs & PhD students, managing people so research happens in a productive way. Whatever output from that group would probably not happen if it wasn't for the head researcher; in that sense, he/she has a very strong involvement in the creation of a research output. Good research heads will know very well where the different pieces/outputs fit in the overall research project, although they may not be familiar with the details of a calculation in a publication. They will guide provide post-docs and students so their publications fit within the overall project. In my book, this merits co-authorship in a publication.

In addition, there is co-authorship as a signal of group productivity, which is then used to improve the standing of the head researcher when it comes to funding application. This is a game played by many labs in the world; one may not agree with the 'corruption' of traditional authorship, but it is certainly used that way. Thus, I do not think we can discuss the ethics of co-authorship in a vacuum, without understanding its role in modern research practice.

Disclaimer: I do work in a small group, where there is no assumption of automatic co-authorship. I am, however, evaluated on the 'creation and support of research environment' when applying for academic promotion.

Comment: "Whatever output from that group would probably not happen if it wasn't for the head researcher; in that sense, he/she has a very strong involvement in the creation of a research output."  Are you saying that if the head is not involved in the research for a paper, then that paper doesn't happen? If so, this is not true at all, in my experience. In many cases I know of, a post-doc has done the work completely and published it himself/herself, with no help/involvement by the head.

Comment: I'm not saying that at all. What I'm saying is that there would be no research group without the head. No post-docs, no PhD students, no papers.

Comment: Well, if that was what you were trying to say, it was not clear. Paying someone's salary is *not* involvement in research, imo. Please see reason no 1. in [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/19389/285).

Comment: I did say 'create an environment where that research can thrive', which is much broader than paying a salary. I could hire you, pay your salary and, at the same time, put you in a non-productive environment. Deciding the lines of research and putting together a team to achieve them is not a small feat. In fact, it is often harder than doing the actual research.

Answer (score 5):

Any question involving the words "Automatic" and "Authorship" raises red flags for me, and my inclination is always to say "No".

From the International Committee of Medical Journal Editors, which is the group that sets authorship guidelines not only for medical journals, but also many journals in closely related fields like public health:

> Authorship confers credit and has important academic, social, and financial implications. Authorship also implies responsibility and accountability for published work. The following recommendations are intended to ensure that contributors who have made substantive intellectual contributions to a paper are given credit as authors, but also that contributors credited as authors understand their role in taking responsibility and being accountable for what is published.

Automatic authorship doesn't confer either this responsibility, or imply that they've made substantive intellectual contributions to the papers. Their four suggested criteria is as follows:

> Substantial contributions to the conception or design of the work; or the acquisition, analysis, or interpretation of data for the work; AND
>   Drafting the work or revising it critically for important intellectual content; AND
>   Final approval of the version to be published; AND
>   Agreement to be accountable for all aspects of the work in ensuring that questions related to the accuracy or integrity of any part of the work are appropriately investigated and resolved.

I think that in *most* cases an advisor should have met the first criteria, and *should* have met all the subsequent ones for papers with their name on it done by one of their students (otherwise, what exactly is the advisor doing besides signing the occasional form?), but it's entirely possible they haven't.

For example, in my dissertation, I have two papers that do not have my advisors name on them - one because it was a side musing born out of trying to graph a set of results, and pretty much the product of my own brain over the course of a week, and another because they felt they hadn't met those criteria.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think one can claim this is ‘unethical’ in general.

We can (at least for the purpose of argument) take ‘unethical’ to mean ‘deceptive’, in which case ‘is automatic authorship unethical?’ can be read as ‘is automatic authorship deceptive?’  But that depends on who, in the readership, is being deceived, and different disciplines may ‘read’ the author list differently.

My presence in an author list may indicate a claim that:

1. I contributed to this paper, and my position in the list order reflects the importance of my contribution.
2. I contributed to this paper, and my position in the list reflects the alphabetisation of my name.
3. I contributed to this paper, and my position in the list represents the order in which the various authors first committed edits to the text in github.
4. I at least read this paper, and my inclusion in the list reflects the fact that I, along with 800 other people, was during the relevant period funded 50% or more of my time to work on this collaboration (actually, in this case you can't really tell whether or not I'm even aware the paper exists).
5. I'm aware of this paper (which happened in my lab) and am the PI who got the funding (I get the impression, as others have remarked, that this is common in biomedical fields).

As long as the readership of the paper parses the author list in the way I expect, then no-one has been deceived, even if someone from a different area, who parses author lists differently, would get the wrong impression, and might think I was claiming something I'm not (and therefore reproach me for being unethical in doing so).

**So** – I think the answer to the question ‘is “automatic authorship” unethical?’ is: it depends on what you mean by ‘automatic’, ‘authorship’ and ‘unethical’ (we can perhaps take ‘is’ as unproblematic), and depends *crucially* on what author and reader believe is being communicated by one's presence and location in an author list.

---

I've written papers under each set of rules apart from the fifth.  In one similar case, however (anecdote alert), I was on a five-author paper where almost all of the actual writing was done by the PI of the grant and me, in that order; the PI sequenced me first in the author list, then the second, third and fourth authors, then him last, to log the fact that he was the PI, even though you couldn't then tell how much he'd written.  I didn't think this was very fair to him, but he asserted this was the norm in his discipline (a different area of physics).

Some disciplines seem to observe more than one of these parsing rules.

Of course, all of this means that bibliometrics which count things like ‘first-author papers’ are so errorprone as to be essentially pointless, for this as for so many other reasons.

Comment: Related: [What is the point of listing 1000 authors for a single scientific paper?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63440/what-is-the-point-of-listing-1000-authors-for-a-single-scientific-paper), and also [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/66808/11365)

Comment: @ff524 Indeed: thanks for the links to these (I hadn't initially appreciated this was a 2-year old question, which I must have come to via the sidebar!)

Answer (score 2):

First point to counter the "taking credits away": it is your choice to add an "author's contribution" chapter to your manuscript. If you feel pressure to put your supervisor or chief of lab you can do so. If they did not participate in your research, you can simply write "chief - responsible for project fundings". Two things can happen, the reviewers or the editor in chief reject this author for not participating enough. Then it is less pressure that you yourself offended your supervisor, who will later grade you. Or they do not care and the paper goes published, but with exactly this authors contribution. You always have the chance, to not even write this on your own. You can ask all coauthors to give you a summary of their contribution. Formulate that you consider this too sensitive to write on your own and sent to all co-authors. An "empty" co-author has to visibly lie in their response, which is a lot less likely to happen.

Also question yourself, if your supervisor is really not participating? If it is only 5 minutes per week discussion, but within the 5 minutes he/she prevents you with their knowledge from wasting 2 weeks on the wrong statistical method, there is no ethical conflict to grant and offer them co-authorship. If they never participate though it is unethical in my opinion. Regardless of the field. But strongly question yourself, how much has this person influenced your scientific thinking.